# Unable to request secure token using CURL, "User authentication failed"

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using PHP to request a secure token from the Paypal server to call a hosted page. I have followed the directions on https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/gs_ppa_hosted_pages/ to add a user to my Paypal Advanced account and have set up the Hosted Checkout Page as indicated. I have used layout C but changing to A or B doesn't change anything.

The code I am using to request the token is as follows:

```
$url = 'https://payflowpro.paypal.com';
$token = md5('saltedtobechangedlater' . time() );

$info = "PARTNER=paypal&
         VENDOR=[my merchant login]&
         USER=[username I created]&
         PWD=[password I assigned]&
         TRXTYPE=S&
         CURRENCY=USD&
         AMT=1.00&
         CREATESECURETOKEN=Y&
         MODE=TEST&
         SECURETOKENID=$token";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $info);
$content = curl_exec($ch);

$err = curl_errno($ch);
$errmsg = curl_error($ch) ;
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if( $err ){
    echo "<pre>Error. $err\n$errmsg\n";
    print_r($info);
    echo '</pre>';
}

echo $content;
```

The response is: "RESULT=1&RESPMSG=User authentication failed". I have made sure that my hosted page is set as test.

Comment: User authentication failed. Error is caused by one or more of the following:  

- Invalid Processor information entered. Contact merchant bank to verify.    
- "Allowed IP Address" security feature implemented. The transaction is coming from an unknown IP address. 
  
- You are using a test (not active) account to submit a transaction to the live PayPal servers. Change the URL from pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com to payflowpro.paypal.com.

Comment: Can you try with PARTNER=PayPal& ? (I'm not sure if in your original request you are passing this value correctly)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but you said I am using a test account to submit to the live servers? I have set the hosted page to be in test mode in the manager page and have added the MODE=TEST parameter in the curl request.